# "GCC could not be found" while installing Fontforge on os x

Tags: macos, llvm-gcc, fontforge

Just want to install Fontforge on mac os x, 
and firstly tried: `brew install fontforge` 
but got `Error: Failed executing: make (fontforge.rb:38)` 
 and then tried `brew install fontforge --use-clang`
 but still the same error.

Then I tried `brew install fontforge --use-gcc`
 however `Error: GCC could not be found` 
But the `gcc --version`  shows `i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2 (GCC) 4.2.1.....`
and alse I've installed `xcode`,  `command line tools for xcode`,  `cairo`

I'm a newbie on mac and have totally lost, what should I do?
Any suggestions would be appreciated and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well, it has been solved by this:

https://github.com/mxcl/homebrew/issues/11457